# After editing my file via Ruby methods, strange characters appeared

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have this small script which I wrote to rename variables in my JS file.

```
  puts "Current name?"
  current_name = gets.chomp
  puts "New name? (Recommended usage of $ prefix)"
  new_name = gets.chomp
  #
  File.open(file_name, 'r+') do |file|
    file_content = file.read
    edited_file = file_content.sub "var "+current_name+" = ", "var "+new_name+" = "
    edited_file = edited_file.gsub current_name+".", new_name+"." 
    file.truncate(0)
    file.write(edited_file)
  end
```

When I run it, it changes all variable names and that looks just fine in my Atom text editor. But if I open this same file in Sublime text editor all characters are bunch of numbers.

Look at the screenshot (Sublime editor in front and Atom in background)

[image]

After trying this: [Write and read a file with utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163339/write-and-read-a-file-with-utf-8-encoding)

```
  File.open(file_name, 'r+:UTF-8') do |file|
    file_content = file.read
    edited_file = file_content.sub "var "+current_name+" = ", "var "+new_name+" = "
    edited_file = edited_file.gsub current_name+".", new_name+"."
    file.truncate(0)
    file.write edited_file
  end
```

The invalid characters still appear and valid output afterwards. Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it might have to do with encoding

Comment: @PetrGazarov Yeah, that is most likely the issue. Is there any way to set encoding ?

Comment: Also done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274605/ruby-search-file-text-for-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-given-value).
Saves you the "pain" of rewinding and truncating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a hunch—but can't test it since I'm not at a computer—that `File#truncate` doesn't reset the File object's internal "cursor." Since you did `file.read` the cursor is at the end of the file (say, 500 bytes from the beginning). `truncate` deletes everything in the file but the cursor is still at offset 500, so when you write to the file it starts writing at that position, and the preceding bytes are all set to `00` (`NUL`).

When you open the file in Atom, it chooses to not display those `00` bytes. (If you can configure Atom to display invisible characters, you should. A text editor should never hide non-printable characters.) Sublime, on the other hand, sees all the `00`s and decides to display the file as a binary file in a hex view.

The fact that the first three non-zero bytes shown in Sublime are `76 61 72`—the ASCII codes for `var`—would seem to support this theory.

I think the easiest solution would be to call `file.rewind` before `file.truncate` or `file.write`:

```
File.open(file_name, 'r+') do |file|
  file_content = file.read
  file_content.sub!("var #{current_name} = ", "var #{new_name} = ")
  file_content.gsub!("#{current_name}.", "#{new_name}.")

  file.rewind
  file.truncate(0)
  file.write(file_content)
end
```

A better solution, perhaps, would be to embrace the prior invention of the wheel and use `sed` or `awk` for this.