# Ruby: Is there a way to specify your encoding in File.write?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file, trello

**TL;DR**

How would I specify the mode of encoding on File.write, or how would one save image binary to a file in a similar fashion?

**More Details**

I'm trying to download an image from a Trello card and then upload that image to S3 so it has an accessible URL. I have been able to download the image from Trello as binary (I believe it is some form of binary), but I have been having issues saving this as a `.jpeg` using `File.write`. Every time I attempt that, it gives me this error in my Rails console:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from /app/app/services/customer_order_status_notifier/card.rb:181:in `write'
```

And here is the code that triggers that:

```
def trello_pics
    @trello_pics ||=
    card.attachments.last(config_pics_number)&.map(&:url).map do |url|
      binary = Faraday.get(url, nil, {'Authorization' => "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"#{ENV['TRELLO_PUBLIC_KEY']}\", oauth_token=\"#{ENV['TRELLO_TOKEN']}\""}).body
      File.write(FILE_LOCATION, binary) # doesn't work
      run_me
    end
  end
```

So I figure this must be an issue with the way that File.write converts the input into a file. Is there a way to specify encoding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write and read a file with utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163339/write-and-read-a-file-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: [`IO#binwrite`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) From the Docs: "Same as ::write except opening the file in binary mode and ASCII-8BIT encoding"

Comment: Or `File.open(FILE_LOCATION, 'wb') do |file|; file.write(data); end`. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-new

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I don't think so, but I could be wrong

Comment: @max or `File.write(FILE_LOCATION,data, mode: 'wb')` since `IO::write` takes the same mode arguments as `new`

Comment: @engineersmnky if you open a file instance you can write as you stream the response. Otherwise go with the shorter variant. https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/streaming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFIK you can't do it at the time of performing the `write`, but you can do it at the time of creating the `File` object; here an example of UTF8 encoding:

```
File.open(FILE_LOCATION, "w:UTF-8") do 
  |f|
  f.write(....)
end
```

Another possibility would be to use the `external_encoding` option:

```
File.open(FILE_LOCATION, "w", external_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Of course this assumes that the data which is written, is a `String`. If you have (packed) binary data, you would use `"wb"` for openeing the file, and `syswrite` instead of `write` to write the data to the file.

**UPDATE** As engineersmnky points out in a comment, the arguments for the encoding can also be passed as parameter to the `write` method itself, for instance

```
IO::write(FILE_LOCATION, data_to_write, external_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Comment: `IO::write` takes an encoding parameter too.